# Vinyl plank flooring direction in connecting rooms

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I installed vinyl plank in the dining room and now want to continue through landing kitchen and laundry room
The installer said that I need to change the direction of the flooring because it won’t be a straight line from laundry room > landing > kitchen
My question is if it would look weird having the same flooring meeting in the landing in different directions. 
I’ve included a pic to show the “connecting” area. 
I know it may be an aesthetic question but just curious about the pros and cons.

[image: picture of intersection]

Comment: Is diagonal an option? More cuts, but for the small area of the landing perhaps having it "not match any room" would be best. Aesthetically, anyway. Another common reason to change flooring directions is more practical, having to do with expansion/contraction and not having super-long sections that might move so much they buckle.

Comment: This falls into an aesthetics category (taste), which seems to frowned upon here.  However, I would have no issue with having the kitchen & laundry room planking run at right angle to the landing.  One purpose that serves is to break up (visually) the long run that you would see looking from the far end of the kitchen into the laundry, for example.